# How can I set a different styles to a char in TextWatcher in EditText and then save them into SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing notebook app. Each note is a data class that contains "note_text" property. The date class itself is stored in SharedPreferences. I have one EditText and two button "Bold" and "Italic" (there will be more of them in the future and they will be like a check boxes). For applying styles I am using SpanableStringBulder. Every time, TextWacther observes EditText changes and checkes the selected styles in it. Then it apply selected styles to just written char. That was my idea, but problems began.

Firstly, I encountered the styles of previous characters not being preserved with any of the styles. And again, somewhere I tried to solve this by converting to HTML and back. Everything will be saved, but problems with saving spaces and line breaks just started, namely they were cut off.
Secondly, when typing some characters, everything was saved, but as soon as I wrote at least one digit, the styles of all lines also disappeared. The same thing happened if you wrote only numbers and then put one symbol. Also, in the documentation for SpannableStringBuilder, I read that each character with a style is kept in RAM, but I don’t know to what extent this is one of the supposed causes of my problems.
So, I don't how to implement this use case correctly and I need our help!

Code of WriteActivity class:

```
class WriteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var note: Note
    private var notePos: Int = -1
    private lateinit var bind: ActivityWriteBinding
    private var isBold = false
    private var isItalic = false

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        bind = ActivityWriteBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(bind.root)

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        note = intent.getSerializableExtra("note") as Note
        notePos = intent.getIntExtra("note_pos", 0)
        bind.toolbar.title = ""
        bind.title.text = note.title
        bind.title.isSelected = true
        setSupportActionBar(bind.toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        bind.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            newNote = Pair(note, notePos)
            finish()
        }

        bind.EDText.requestFocus()
        bind.EDText.setText(SpannableString(trimTrailingWhitespace(Html.fromHtml(note.text, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY))), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
        bind.EDText.setSelection(bind.EDText.length())

        bind.boldButton.setOnClickListener {
            isBold = !isBold
        }

        bind.italicButton.setOnClickListener {
            isItalic = !isItalic
        }

        bind.EDText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count1: Int) {
                if (bind.EDText.text.isNotEmpty() && count1 > before && (isItalic || isBold))
                    updateTextFormatting(bind.EDText.selectionStart-1, SpannableStringBuilder(bind.EDText.text.toSpanned()))
                note.text = Html.toHtml(bind.EDText.text.toSpanned(), FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
                Log.d("html", Html.toHtml(bind.EDText.text.toSpanned(), FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY))
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        newNote = Pair(note, notePos)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        newNote = Pair(note, notePos)
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()

        newNote = Pair(note, notePos)
    }

    private fun updateTextFormatting(pos: Int, text: SpannableStringBuilder) {

        if (text.isNotBlank() && text[pos] != ' ') {
            if (isBold) {
                text.setSpan(
                    StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
                    pos,
                    pos + 1,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
            }

            if (isItalic) {
                text.setSpan(
                    StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC),
                    pos,
                    pos + 1,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
            }

            bind.EDText.setText(text)
            bind.EDText.setSelection(pos + 1)
        }
    }

    private fun trimTrailingWhitespace(source: CharSequence?): CharSequence {
        if (source == null) return ""
        var i = source.length

        // loop back to the first non-whitespace character
        while (--i >= 0 && Character.isWhitespace(source[i])) {}
        return source.subSequence(0, i + 1)
    }
}
```

Code of "Note" data class:

```
data class Note(val id: String = "",
                var title: String,
                var icon: String,
                var text: String = "",
                var date: String = "",
                var isFavorite: Boolean = false) : java.io.Serializable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$title is title"
    }
}
```